# Mathematicians Death Bed Password

Tags: riddle, cipher, password

A famous mathematician was found on his deathbed this evening, leaving behind his life's work trapped away on his computer.

Protected by a password, it is believed this computer contains many groundbreaking equations that have yet to be released to the public.

Luckily, it seems, our mathematician was aware of his timely demise and left us a note, ensuring his works only went to someone intellectually worthy. The note thus read:

---

> It seems my time has come at last, for like many before me, I have met my demise. I'm sure you'll want my life's works, they're ever such a prize. Are you worthy?
>
> > For Fibonacci was right,
> > if only he'd gone further he'd have shed some light,
> > for me aabcehmu is just not enough for a key,
> > yet it's taken as credence,
> > just adding one to each of his sequence,
> > just remember to playfair,
> > for names leave a legacy,
>
> signed hpssodge

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think I have found the password.

Step 1

> Firstly the aabcehmu stands for Fibonacci is the alphabetic representation of the Fibonacci sequence.
>  Now according to letter "just adding one to each of his sequence" we need to add one to each letter of the Fibonacci. and you will get
> bbcdfinv

Step 2

> 'hpssodge' is a message which we need to decode using Playfair Cipher
>  so When you Decrypt hpssodge with key as bbcdfinv you will get

The password

> puzzling

Comment: That was a little bit quicker than I had hoped haha.. I should have made it harder!